Why is the "Move left/right a space" shortcut slow, when "Switch to Desktop X" is fast?
This drives me crazy.
I am using MacOS Sonoma 14.4 on M1 Max macbook.
When using shortcuts to move left/right a space, not only the animation is slow, but then the time to interactivity is also slow. Whereas if I jump to the same space using the "Switch to Desktop" shortcut, it is fast as expected.
To reproduce:

Open text editor on both space/desktop 1 and 2
Use the same shortcut as I show here, which you can set up in Keyboard shortcuts under mission control
from space 2, compare the speed of going left to space 1 and then try to type as soon as possible, and compare that with doing the same but using the "Switch to desktop 1" shortcut instead.

Please tell me I am not the only one! I want to find a solution for this.


It always has been. idk why, but it seems to have been designed that way.

I use Spaces every day with Cmd-left/right, the animations are irrelevant to me.

How much faster is switching to a desktop compared to the move left/right shortcut? On my Intel Mac, both shortcuts are equally fast.

@jaume Do you use Accessibility > Display > Reduce motion? it makes it easier to see the difference. It's as if it was waiting for "move" the animation to finish even though there's none. Switching desktop is instantaneous, but when using the move action, it's about 2.5 seconds until it becomes interactive again.

No, I don't use "Reduce motion". If I enable it, the animation is slower, but I still see no difference between the two shortcuts. I've noticed that when I select a space with a large number of windows, the animation takes longer the first time the space is displayed, independently of whether "Reduce motion" is enabled or of the shortcut used, but afterwards there is no difference between the two shortcuts, so I  guess that's not the issue. I can't reproduce the issue you describe... I really wonder what's causing the 2.5-second delay....

@jaume I believe it must be an issue that occurs only on Macs with ARM architecture (M1 etc)

The animations are terribly slow unless you manually tweak them with something like the following command:
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1; killAll Finder && killAll Dock
After doing that, the animation will be fast regardless of the method you use to switch desktops

Nope, it doesn't change anything regarding the issue I am describing.

If you switch two times, one right after another, does it still lose an input event or does it work? What I noticed is that this change helps with the animation timeout, so it unblocks interactions faster, even if the animation itself still looks almost the same.

oh, I had a typo, killAll Dock instead of killAll Doc
